# Game of Life Pygame

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pygame, cell, conways-game-of-life

I am creating the game of life in python. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly though.

The get_cell function does not seem right to me. Also I would like to use this function in the count_neighbors function.

What am I doing wrong, or what could be done better?

```
import pygame
import time
import sys

HEIGHT = 50
WIDTH = 50

SCALE = 10
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE))


def create_blank():
    """Creates a HEIGHT x WIDTH list containing all zero's. The inner lists 
    will all be WIDTH long and the outer list will HEIGHT long."""
    board = [[0]*WIDTH]*HEIGHT
    return board


def get_cell(board, x, y):
    """Returns the game board at position x,y , this is 1 if the cell at that 
    position is alive and 0 if the cell is dead. If the x or y parameters are
    out of bounds (not valid coordinates), the function returns 0."""
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            return board[y][x]
    else:
        return 0


def count_neighbours(board, x, y):
    """Counts the number of alive neighbours around the position x,y , including 
    diagonal neighbours. Does not include the cell itself."""
    count = 0
    for i in range(x-1,x+2):
      for j in range(y-1,y+2):
        if not(i == x and j == y):
                count += int(mat[i][j])


def update(board):
    """Creates a new board copy and applies the game rules to each cell using 
    the old board. Does not modify the old board. Returns the new board."""
    if(count < 2 or count > 3):
      return 0
    elif count == 3:
      return 1
    else:
      return mat[i][j]
```

I am not getting any errors and the board is appearing, but still this does not look right to me...

Comment: In what way does it not look right to you?

Comment: I am not sure if it is valid because I can't really test. Does this function seem possible to you, and does do what needs to be done?

Comment: In `get_cell` you replace `x` and `y` with values from the ranges. These will start counting at zero. So, you will always return `board[0][0]`. Really you should just return `board[x][y]` with not loops through ranges. You could check whether `x` and `y` are valid first, and return `0` otherwise.

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Comment: And sure as hell don't [plagiarize](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/31817)! ([revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33163325/7))

Comment: Continued vandalism will result in moderator intervention. Please just leave the post alone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
board = [[0]*WIDTH]*HEIGHT
```

The term instances each row of your board with the same object (instead of `HEIGHT` copies, as you might have expected).

Maybe the following example will make things clear:

```
>>> WIDTH=2
>>> HEIGHT=3
>>> board = [[0]*WIDTH]*HEIGHT
>>> board
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> board[1][1] = 3
>>> board
[[0, 3], [0, 3], [0, 3]]
```

However, if you use

```
board = [[0 for x in range(WIDTH)] for y in range(HEIGHT)]
```

instead (i.e. creating a new instance of a row each time) the result looks like this:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 3], [0, 0]]
```

**EDIT** Further improvements

I would recommend to use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

...

board = np.zeros([HEIGHT,WIDTH], dtype=int)

...

def count_neighbours(board, x, y):
    return np.sum(board[x-1:x+2][y-1:y+2]) - board[x][y]
```

Comment: Yes thanks! Did you have a chance to look at the others?

Answer (score 1):

You're making a mistake of iterating over a range, rather than checking membership in the range:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> for x in range(5):
...     print x
1
2
3
4
5
```

Instead of `for ... in`, you need to use `if ... in`. `for` is a loop, `if` is a branch:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> if x in range(5):
...     print x
3
```

So, `get_cell` will be:

```
def get_cell(board, x, y):
    if x in range(WIDTH) and y in range(HEIGHT):
        return board[y][x]
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Others already told you what the problem of your code is, but note that you could simplify it by using a `set` instead of nested lists.

Here's a full example, using a `set` for the board and pygame for displaying it. Use the mousebutton to create or kill a cell.

```
import pygame
from itertools import product, chain

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
board = {(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(2,3),(2,2),(3,3),(3,2)}
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1500)

CELLSIZE = 32
H_CELLSIZE = CELLSIZE / 2

def neighbors(point):
    x,y = point
    for dx, dy in product((-1,0,1), repeat=2):
        if dx != 0 or dy != 0:
            if x + dx >= 0 and y + dy >= 0:
                yield x + dx, y + dy

def step(board):
    new_board = set()
    with_neighbors = board | set(chain(*map(neighbors, board)))
    for point in with_neighbors:
        count = sum((neigh in board) for neigh in neighbors(point))
        if count == 3 or (count == 2 and point in board):
            new_board.add(point)
    return new_board

def scr_to_board(pos):
    x, y = pos
    return (x / CELLSIZE , y / CELLSIZE)

def board_to_scr(pos):
    x, y = pos
    return (x * CELLSIZE + H_CELLSIZE, y * CELLSIZE + H_CELLSIZE)

while True:
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): 
        break

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            board ^= {scr_to_board(pygame.mouse.get_pos())}
        if e.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            board = step(board)

    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('white'))
    for cell in board:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.color.Color('black'), board_to_scr(cell), H_CELLSIZE, 0)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image]